# acl in grails using roles

Tags: security, grails, acl, roles

I'm working on a Grails application where I do a user authentication based on session verification. Every user has a role, that I assign to it when I create the user. I want to limit access to links depending on roles. For example an admin can create and delete a user, a normal user can't do that. How can I do it in a simple easy way?

Here is the user.groovy:

```
class User {

    transient securiteService

    String username
    String password
    String nom
    String prenom
    String email
    String tel

    static hasMany = [roles : Role]

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        password blank: false,display: false
        nom nullable: true
        prenom nullable: true
        email email:true, nullable:true
        tel nullable:true, maxSize:20,  matches:/[\+]{0,1}[0-9\s]{3,15}/
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
        sort nom: "asc"
        affectations sort : "dateAffectation", order:"desc"
        intervention sort : "responsable", order:"desc"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the [Grails spring-security-core plugin](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/spring-security-core)?

Comment: i did bu i was lost, i thinj that plugin offers the whole authentification process

Comment: It does. It saves you from having to create it all yourself. If you want an "_simple easy way_", then that is the way. In your controllers you then can simply add `@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")` or something similar and you're done.

Comment: okey, but how does it work, i install the plugin and then the user class and everything is created ?

Comment: That's simply too much information to cover here. You should read the [documentation](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/3.2.x/index.html#gettingStarted). The "Getting started" is a good starting point.

Comment: okey thanks very much